# UIImageView loading different image in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app that runs on all iOS platforms and uses a loading image (iPad, iPad retina, iPhone, iPhone retina, and iPhone 5). The loading image is just a screen shot of the app's log in screen. Pretty normal.

The log in screen has a few buttons, a couple of images for advertising, and a background image. However when I run in the simulator, the background image is not loading correctly. I can't tell if it's using an image from elsewhere (nothing that looks like it is included in the project), or just background color but it is a very light tan color. This happens on all 3 hardware versions of the iPhone sim, but doesn't happen on the iPad sim. If I run on actual devices, the background image loads just fine on all devices.

A little more information: I am following the naming convention of

- ~iphone.png
- @2x~iphone.png
- ~ipad.png
- @2x~ipad.png

I am using two storyboards. One for iPad and one for iPhone. The background image is a UIImageView, and is defined within Xcode's Attribute Inspector (not programmatically).

I have tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the app from the simulator
- Changing the image to something else then back.

Comment: And if you change the image, do you see the new image on the simulator? Or you see always the "old" one?

Comment: I see the new one. What weird behavior.

Comment: Uhm...and If you now open the new image, paste inside the old one and save, without changing the file but only its content? :) however, very strange (I assume that when you write "clean" you mean both clean option: clean and clean build folder)